# How to delete image file using deleteAll() - cakephp-upload-plugin

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using **cakephp - upload plugin** downloaded from https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload

When I delete a single record using delete() method, the image file is automatically deleted, but when I delete multiple records using deleteAll() method, the files are not deleted automatically.

Here is the code :

```
$modelClassObject->deleteAll($conditions);
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: [read the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#deleteall) Compare to your own code. As is your question will be closed because your code is not in the question.

Comment: @AD7six. I have read the document and now I am using **$modelClassObject->deleteAll($conditions,TRUE,TRUE);** instead of **$modelClassObject->deleteAll($conditions);** 
This works for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: :/ write an answer and accept it - also put your original code in the question. **Don't write comments** containing code, to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Code (This works for me.):
`$modelClassObject->deleteAll($conditions,TRUE,TRUE);`

Old Code :
`$modelClassObject->deleteAll($conditions);`

Comment: `old code` should be in the question - +1 for answering your own question (don't forget to accept it).